# help with solving a simple differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this differential equation:
$(x-y)dy=(x+y+1)dx$
This is simple but I am unable to solve this can someone help me with this?

Comment: You will need an integrating factor

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: I'm on my phone but I can when I get home :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{x+y+1}{x-y}$$
Set $x=X-\frac 12$ and $y=Y-\frac 12$, we have 
$$Y'=\frac{X+Y}{X-Y}=\frac{1+\frac{Y}{X}}{1-\frac{Y}{X}}$$
let $Y=UX$, therefore
$$U+XU'=\frac{1+U}{1-U}$$
$$XU'=\frac{1+U^2}{1-U}$$
$$\frac{1-U}{1+U^2}dU=\frac{dX}{X}$$
thus
$$\tan^{-1}U-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+U^2)=c+\ln X$$
Now set $U=\frac{y+\frac 12}{x+\frac 12}$

Comment: The argument of the logarithm on the left-hand side of the final result is not quite correct.

Comment: Sorry it was edited